# ArcMap 10.1 Crashing when using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, field-calculator, csv

I keep getting a serious error message when I try to use the field calculator. I've joined a .csv to my SDE feature class and am trying to set one of the columns equal to one of the columns from the .csv. But it keeps crashing! Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Does it crash as soon as you open Field Calc, when you start typing, when you run the code, etc? Does this happen on other datasets? What if you remove the .csv?

Comment: @Paul It crashes once it's started on the calculation. And yes, it happens on other datasets. Also, I have to keep the .csv joined because it contains the values to populate my records with.

Comment: Please add the code that you have in Field Calc then.

Comment: WATEROWNER.S_MANHOLE.ORIENTATION = 
[orientationpart1_1.csv.ORIENTATIO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Field Calculator would crash on me whenever I would run the Field Calculator to update about 2,300 records on a point dataset that was generated as a checkout file geodatabase.  This turned out to be a known ESRI bug where ArcMap would crash if the Field Calculator was used on more than 100 records at a time in a checkout file GDB, and was addressed in 10.2.2 and is no longer an issue.   I don't know if upgrading to 10.2.2 will eliminate your field calculator issue but it worked for mine.

Comment: Here is the list of all the bug fixes addressed in the 10.2.2 release including the field calculator issue (NIM091189).         http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/1022-IssuesAddressedList.pdf

Comment: I am once again experiencing the above mentioned bug.  I have already sent bug reports to ESRI so hopefully it will be readdressed at some point.